# Create a new font from FakeBold

Tags: fonts, fontspec

The fontspec package proposes a nice `FakeBold=1.5` to create a fake bold with various weight. It works nicely, except that I feel like anti-aliasing is not working as nicely in Okular (my understanding is that it adds a contour to the shape, and then I guess it disturbs the aliasing) Since I want my document to print nicely with any viewer, I would like to export this fake font into a proper font. How could I do that?

If it helps, I need to create a semi bold to `NimbusSanL-ReguItal`:

```
\newfontface\mySemibold{NimbusSanL-ReguItal.ttf}[
  FakeBold=1.8,
]
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%% See also "Choosing additional NFSS font faces" for a cleaner solution
%% Downloaded here https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/document-viewer-fontpack/blob/master/font-sources/ghostscript%20urw/NimbusSanL-Regu.ttf
\newfontface\mySemibold{NimbusSanL-ReguItal.ttf}[
  FakeBold=1.8,
]

\begin{document}

Here is a test

{\mySemibold Here is a test} % <-- I want to create a font for this

\textbf{Here is a test}

\end{document}
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex 
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t 
%%% End:
```

**EDIT**

I tried to use font forge, but without much success. The tool is easy to use, but the result not great. If I try to interpolate between the two fonts regulItal et BoldItal, some glyphs are greatly converted… while others, like `a` are just garbage.

[image]

I also tried to select the glyph and do `Element > Style > Change weight`, the result is better but not perfect either (see for instance the curved edges):

[image]

Don't know if I did something wrong, but I can't reproduce for now what `FakeBold` is doing.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` never use either of those with luatex or xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem is that if I remove these lines, the `\usepackage{txfonts}` is not applied… and I don't want to mess with the template I am using since they expect me to use this font/package.

Comment: the only thing inputenc does is issue a warning that it should not be used then quits, T1 fontenc will break hyphenation in xetex and prevent use of unicode fonts with luatex unless you undo its effects, txfonts package will detect luatex and use Opentype TU fonts anyway, if they expect you to use those packages they expect pdftex and you should not use luatex (this appies to most journal publisher submissions for example)

Comment: Technically, I will just send a pdf here in that case, so lualatex is fine. But if I remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` will not work, and I also can't do `\textbf{…}`. If there is a clean way to solve this, I am interested. I guess I could not use `txfonts` at all and manually try to find equivalent fonts… but it seems a bit scary, notably it will certainly break math fonts I guess.

Comment: Those don't depend on using the T1 encoding. But if the point is you've been told which fonts to use, then why do you think they'll accept something with your new font? In any case, there is no way to avoid sub-optimal results here. There's a reason font designers create separate weights rather than a single weight which is then automatically modified to produce the others.

Comment: why do you think `\textbf` etc don't work by default in lualatex and you have to break all its unicode font support to get it?????

Comment: what fakebold is doing is stroking rather than filling the font path so the black area is not produced by filling an outline path, so converting that to an outline fiont requires some rather hard maths or just producing it at high resolution and generating new outline curves by approximation, either way it isn't any kind of simple format conversion.

Comment: @cfr well at least in the above MWE, if I remove the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the last line will not be bold. And this new font is only to highlight a few words, like I could put regular bold but then it is confusing because bold are already for paragraphs. So nothing too serious compared to changing the font of the whole document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, I’m not saying that `\textbf` do not work in general, but with the above MWE, commenting `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` breaks the last `\textbf{…}` (that displays like regular text), and ignore the `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` line… no idea why, but guess that `\usepackage{txfonts}` is not really compatible with this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well at least tools like Inkscape have options to turn the stroke to a path, and then boolean operations on path are also well supported in Inkscape https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.0#Changed_behavior_of_Stroke_to_Path Tools like font-forge also seem to have advanced math operations, not sure if we can do the above from font-forge alone, or export each glyph to svg, use inkscape to change that glyph, and import it back into the font… no idea how fontforge can deal with that.

Comment: Ok, so I just found a solution that works, but that is quite tedious to run without scripting: 1) open the font in fontforge 2) File/Generate font > choose svg format 3) open the file in Inkscape 4) Go to Text > SVG Font Editor 5) In the Generic setting tab, click on "Prepare canvas" 6) In the Glyph tab, click on the glyph you want to change, and click Edit. It will create under the hood a new layer with your glyph. 7) Click on the letter, and add a stroke to it (via the panel "fill and stroke") 8) Path > Stroke to path 9) right click + ungroup 10) select 2 shapes+Path > Union…

Comment: … 11) select the new object, and assign it back to the glyph by clicking "Obtain curve" in the Glyph tab. 12) repeat for all glyph (!!), I need to find how to script that 13) save your file 13) Open your file in fontforge, the new glyphs should appear 14) you can test it with "Window > metric" 15) Generate from it a new ttf font. Enjoy. Now, this process is quite long to repeat on all glyphs, now I’d prefer to find how to script it.

Comment: @tobiasBora yes exactly getting the path from the font and stroking it is easy that's what inkscape and fakebold are doing. Working out a path for a non-overlapping _outline_ of that stroked region is computationaly hard. You could ask about fontforge scripting but don't ask me (I don't know) and don't ask here (it's off topic) fontforge questions could be asked at graphic design or stackoverflow I guess.

Comment: you shouldn't use txfonts like this with lualatex. That is a package meant for pdftex.

Comment: @tobiasBora If you want to get `fontforge`'s "Change weight" to produce somthing similar to fontspec's FakeBold, you should select the `CJK` option and `Counters: Squish`. The it tries to do pretty much what fontspec does. It might still fail sometimes, but that's because doing that in a font is hard.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Oh indeed, good point, it seems to be much better this way (I thought that `CJK` was for chinease stuff), thanks a lot!

Comment: @tobiasBora It is, but for these purposes east-asian scripts are much easier (because they don't have such a strong baseline, x-height and capital height, so there is less need to adapt characters to fit such dimensions). Therefore the CJK mode basically just turns off all the special handling and just leaves you with something similar to what `fontspec` is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you willing to use the FontForge font editor? This is not hard, if your are not using a vast number of characters.

Although FontForge has the ability to change glyph weight, I have found that its algorithm is not satisfactory. Instead, you can do what `fontspec` is doing, when it strokes the glyph outlines. I like the results.

Load the font into FontForge, select glyphs, and copy them to background. Then use the menu Element > Expand Stroke. You do not need all it provides. Just look at the numbers for major axis and minor axis.

That will convert the glyph into an outlined shape (hollowed). Copy the background (original glyph) to the foreground (hollowed outline) and use Element > Overlap > Remove Overlap. You may also wish to do routine tasks such as add extrema, simplify, round to integer.

Although this is inherently a graphic arts question, it is inspired by `fontspec`. A couple of weeks ago I asked (here) how it was done.

Note that the expanded glyph will have its lowest point lower than baseline, its highest point higher than ascender, its width greater than before. If you wish, you can scale/move, but it is probably not necessary for small changes.

Incidentally: The FakeBold does not actually create glyph outlines that can be extracted. It dynamically changes the existing glyphs during PDF creation. If you extract glyphs from the PDF, they will b identical to the original font.

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks a lot, I was really not understanding this weird menu for extending stroke! Just one thing before accepting it: I was also wondering, can we script this? I wanted to try different font weight, and this seems quite tedious to do manually for any single glyph & size. (Just, note for myself, the "copy to backgroud" refers to Ctrl-C, and then click on the "Arrière" layer (translated background certainly) below the editing tools when editing the glyph before the Ctrl-V, and the "expand stroke" is translated as "Etendre ligne", which is NOT in the style menu)

Comment: Actually, I think I found a solution for the script, testing it now

Comment: @tobiasBora I do not script FontForge, but apparently you can do it. Yes, the stroke dialog box is fancier than necessary.

Comment: Ok, I just did it and created a nicer script for that, see my other answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I ended up adapting the great answers of @rallg and @marcel-krüger into a script. The script is actually fairly simple, basically:

```
font = fontforge.open(filename)
for glyph in set(font):
    font[glyph].foreground = (font[glyph].foreground.stroke("circular", 40)
                              + font[glyph].foreground).removeOverlap().addExtrema().simplify().round()
font.generate(out_filename)
```

but I still ended up creating [a script](https://github.com/tobiasBora/make-font-bolder) so that we can easily use it from command line. If you have nix, you can just run:

```
$ nix run github:tobiasBora/make-font-bolder -- --size 30 YourInputFont.ttf YourOutputFont.ttf
```

or install `fontforge` and run the `make-font-bolder` pyhon script. See the documentation with `-h` to use different methods/stroke shape etc. Result:

[image]

Comment: Extremely useful! But do review the characters (select characters, then FF menu > Element > validation > find problems, open and intersecting paths). Other problems, such as missing extema, are unimportant.